# C# set row background color in a datagridview depending on the content

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to call a specific data from the db.

```
private void textBox25_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from V_CustomerUnits2  where unitmodel like N'%" + textBox25.Text + "%'", con);
        DataTable DATA = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DATA);
        dataGridView4.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in DATA.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView4.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = "false";
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["fixid"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["CompanyName"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["unitmodel"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["unitserial"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["manufacturer"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["problemdesc"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["technotes"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["dateaddedunit"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["datefixed"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["total"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["invoicestatus"].ToString();
            dataGridView4.Rows[n].Cells[12].Value = item["invoicen"].ToString();
            Countrecords.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

I need the back color of each row to be based on a specific result.

For example, if the  unit is repaired, color is green, if not repaired red, if cannot fix orange.

Any help?

Comment: Thats is not the right way to build SQL and it is far from the best way to populate a DGV...never mind that you are running a query each time they press a key.

Comment: I tried this code without success

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` property on the row than you want. Example:

```
dataGridView4.Rows[n].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: @ Plutonix, whats the best way to build SQl , or example to run the above with different SQL?